# Select rows with exact text in dataframes in Python

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to select the rows whoes "Column_A" has ".2.". My code is as follow.

```
data = {'Column_A':['L.9922070.128.1.020','L.9922080.125.1.001','F.1622002.001.2.001','F.1622002.001.2.001','F.1622002.001.2.001']}
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data)
c = df1[df1["Column_A"].str.contains(".2.")==True]
print(c[["Column_A"]])
```

However, the output is as follows.

```
              Column_A
0  L.9922070.128.1.020
1  L.9922080.125.1.001
2  F.1622002.001.2.001
3  F.1622002.001.2.001
4  F.1622002.001.2.001
```

The output that I want is as follows.

```
              Column_A
2  F.1622002.001.2.001
3  F.1622002.001.2.001
4  F.1622002.001.2.001
```

Please help me to find the error. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because `.` is special regex metacharacter use `regex=False`:

```
c = df1[df1["Column_A"].str.contains(".2.", regex=False)]
```

Or escape it:

```
c = [df1["Column_A"].str.contains(r"\.2\.")]
```